# C code is not running and showing something confusing

Tags: c, mingw

```
PS C:\Users\main> gcc Untitled-1.c
PS C:\Users\main> ./answer
./answer : The term './answer' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check 
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ ./answer
+ ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (./answer:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

VS code is continususly showing me this. At first it showed fatal error and this text at the same time.
I resolved the fatal error but it is still not showing the output. I need to get this threw early.

I tried to change the path of compilation of file. that resolves one fatal error but cannot got resolved this.

Comment: what is the list of files in your folder? Does `answer` exist?

Answer (score 2):

When you compile without specifying an output file, the default output will be `a.exe` on Windows (and `a.out` on Linux flavors).

So your first command is compiling `Untitled-1.c` and producing program `a.exe`.  But you are attempting to run `answer.exe`, which does not exist.

You probably want to modify your build step to be:

```
gcc -o answer.exe Untitled-1.c
```

This is probably done in either `tasks.json` or your makefile